# How to release svnkit resources after log

Tags: java, svnkit

- I use `svnkit` in java application to get svn revisions log, but after finish the process on the `visualVm` some svnkit resource and thread still exist and live .
- ex. **org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.util.SVNHashMap$KeyIterator**, **org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.DefaultSVNRepositoryPool$TimeoutTask**
- And when i try to log more than once it effect the application performance.
- how can i release svnkit resources?
- Code sample:

  ```
  public static SVNLogEntryHandler doLogFully(String[] paths, long startRevision, long endRevision, SVNRepository repository) throws SVNException {
  SVNLogEntryHandler logEntryHandler = new SVNLogEntryHandler();

  repository.log(paths, startRevision, endRevision, true, true, 0, false, null, logEntryHandler);

  return logEntryHandler;
  }
  ```
- story log entry.

  ```
    for (SVNLogEntry logEntry : doLogFully(..,..,..,..,..).getLogEntries()) {
       // store log entry 
     }
  ```
- **Update**

  - i create `SVNRepository` using `SVNRepositoryFactory`.

    ```
    SVNRepository repository = SVNRepositoryFactory.create(SVNURL.parseURIEncoded(repositoryUrl));
        repository.setAuthenticationManager(SVNWCUtil.createDefaultAuthenticationManager(repositoryUserName, repositoryPassword));
    ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run ISVNRepositoryPool#dispose on the connection pool from which you create SVNRepository instance. It will stop the timer.

See also this [article](http://vcs.atspace.co.uk/2012/09/22/what-svnkit-resources-should-be-disposed/) for SVNKit resources releasing.

Comment: I update the question, based on the article and the update i have only to call `repository.closeSession();` to release the resources and connections.?

Comment: What protocol do you use? If you use svn+ssh, SVNKit keeps SSH connection open for about 10 minutes, because otherwise all operations become very slow.

Comment: I use svn and also try `repository.closeSession();` but visualVm still get `org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.DefaultSVNRepositoryPool$TimeoutTask`
`org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.util.SVNHashMap$KeyIterator` .

Comment: And what SVNKit version do you use?

Comment: We had similar bug reports, and the problem was fixed at 1.7.6 version. Could you please try the latest SVNKit version?

Comment: I try svnkit-1.7.9 but i think the issue still exist, i guess i have to `repositoryPool.createRepository` instead of `SVNRepositoryFactory.create` and the `dispose` it, any way thank you for your kindly help, i will accept your answer and if you any additional  information kindly update your answer.